# How can I squash a commit in Git so that I can diff my last commit against the checkout without seeing the interim commits?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using gitlab, and when I commit it gives the code reviewer an opportunity to diff a commit with a previous commit. Some of me commits have distracting debugging code, I don't want that stuff being presented in the merge request. For example:

1. checkout code
2. commit - make some changes also add debug code
3. commit - make some changes also add debug code
4. commit - make some changes, remove all debugging code

So what I want is to be able to diff 4 against 1, but have all the "real" changes rolled up into 4 without any of the debugging code from 2 and 3. Basically, I want to hide some of my sausage making. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can use normal `git` on the command line, and that the hash of the initial checkout is `454354`, you can use `git rebase -i 454354`, and change the `pick` to `squash` for all the commits after the first one and then save the file.

After the rebase, you should see one commit instead of 3.

Comment: But how do I exclude the debugging code from the changes I want to stay?

Comment: @MusicalShore, I do not understand. If you removed the debugging code in the third commit, there should be no more debugging code after the rebase.

Comment: @MusicalShore, The rebase effectively makes one commit that looks like the combination of 2-3-4, which should not contain any debugging code if I am understanding your sequence of commits correctly.

Comment: 2 and 3 contain changes I want to keep and fold into 4. The debugging code I want to eliminate.

Comment: @MusicalShore, When you squash, the changes from 2 and 3 and 4 will all be there.